# Canvas translate function wont work on key trigger

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

When I put `engine.map.ctx.translate(engine.moveX, engine.moveY);` just like that it works perfectly, but when I try to invoke this function on key trigger it gives me nothing.

I'm checking with alert if key triggers works and they do, however `engine.map.ctx.translate(engine.moveX, engine.moveY);` isn't working inside switch statement.

```
var engine = {}
    engine.moveX = 0;
    engine.moveY = 0;

engine.map = {}
    engine.map.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    engine.map.ctx = engine.map.canvas.getContext('2d');

document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    switch(evt.keyCode){
    case 37:
         engine.moveX -= 15;
         engine.map.ctx.translate(engine.moveX, engine.moveY);
         alert('left');
         break;
    case 38:
         engine.moveY -= 15;
         engine.map.ctx.translate(engine.moveX, engine.moveY);
         alert('up');
         break;
    case 39:
         engine.moveX += 15;
         engine.map.ctx.translate(engine.moveX, engine.moveY);
         alert('right');
         break;
    case 40:
         engine.moveY += 15;
         engine.map.ctx.translate(engine.moveX, engine.moveY);
         alert('down');
         break;
    }
};
```

Comment: what should it give, why does it not work, i cant see any error

Comment: that's the problem, i dont see either it should on arrow press move canvas context 15px to direction of clicked arrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ctx.translate` command is not designed to redraw anything

It only repositions the canvas **for subsequent draws**.

So you now need to also redraw your object.

Comment: but why `ctx.translate(-75, -30);` would work outside switch statement but when inside produces nothing?

Comment: Shapes drawn using html canvas are not "movable".  To "move" a shape you must erase it and redraw it in its new position. The html canvas context.translate command moves the canvas origin to the specified x,y, but it doesn't "move" any existing drawings.  It only affects any drawings done **after context.translate**.  I don't have a copy of your code, but I suspect outside the switch statement you are translating+drawing whereas inside the switch statement your are translating-but-not-drawing.

Comment: so lets say i have view of map of tiles 15 tiles on 15 tiles (each of 15px) and but ofc the whole map is a lot bigger and i want on arrow key left to move map left by 1 tile or 15px i need to loop for statement again? And if so if i would make that view of map much bigger and would use more kind of tile images wouldnt my code become  too slow ?

Comment: Canvas is very fast and can handle panning (revealing previously offscreen tiles).  Whether your own app is slow or fast when panning is very much up to your app's design requirements and how performance conscious you are in your coding.

Comment: Thank you so much, still... [link](http://driglou.pusku.com/world/) this is the whole thing i did, so why ctx.translate() function in switch statement and invoked alone gives different effect?